# Too few arguments to function while setting a value in an array of pointers to functions

Tags: c, pointers

I was trying to create an array of function pointers with the following piece of code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int functu(int ,int);
int ghonchu(int,int);

int main()
{
    printf("Hello, World!\n");

    int (*acrib[10]) (int,int);

    acrib[0] = (*functu)(int,int);
    return 0;
}
```

On compiling this program, an error is thrown saying "too few arguments to function 'functu'".

What can be the cause of it? Am I missing anything trivial?

Answer (score 4):

You seem to be confusing `&` (which returns a pointer) with `*` (which dereferences a pointer).

You need to change this:

```
   acrib[0] = (*functu)(int,int);
```

to this:

```
   acrib[0] = &functu;
```

See: http://ideone.com/r1Xqa6

Comment: Got it ! Thanks a lot.

Comment: Problem still persists. Sorry

Comment: @deadpoet: I've added an Ideone.com link.

Comment: The `&` is entirely optional; the code would work correctly with `acrib[0] = functu;`.  In fact, it would also work with `acrib[0] = *functu;` or even (horror of horrors) `acrib[0] = **functu;` — the key point is that the function-invoking left parenthesis is missing.  Personally, I skip the `&`, but I understand the desire to use it.  I'd never use the `*` notation when initializing a function pointer, but I would usually write `(*acrib[0])(10, 20);` rather than `acrib[0](10, 20);`, though that is in part because the latter notation wasn't an option when I learned C.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: That's a good point. I guess it would be more correct to say that the OP was confusing the syntax for declaring a function pointer with the syntax for referring to a function pointer.

Answer (score 0):

You should have function implementation, then assign the implementation to the pointer before using it. [short example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1952175/how-to-call-the-function-using-function-pointer)

Comment: No; that's not necessary.  The function declarations are quite adequate.