# Invoke function using pointer to function in C

Tags: c, function, pointers, syntax

I want to understand how a pointer to function works and how the functions are called in C.

In this example:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void invoked_function();

int main(void) {

     void(*function)();
     function = invoked_function;

     function();  //First way to call invoked_function
     (*function)(); //Second way to call invoked_function

     return 0;
}

void invoked_function() {
     printf("Hi, I'm the invoked function\n\n");
}
```

I call the function `invoked_function` using `function();` and `(*function)();`, both work actually.

If the first one contanis the memory address of `invoked_function`, and the second contains the first byte of the code of `invoked_function`, why are working both?

Comment: Because the language is constructed this way.

Comment: Instead of writing a novel with code-snippets, provide a [mcve].

Comment: "the second contains the first byte of the code of `invoked_function`".  No.  That would be true if `function` were a pointer-to-char.  But it's not, it's a pointer-to-*function*.  So `function` is the pointer, and `*function` is the function, and `(*function)()` is the logical way to call it.  But since there's not much you can do with a function pointer except call it, when you write `function()`, without the `*`, the compiler (for once in its tiny, narrow-minded life) says, "Oh, okay, I guess you're trying to call the pointed-to function, so that's what we'll do."

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This:

```
function = invoked_function;
```

is equivalent to this:

```
function = &invoked_function;
```

since the first is also valid since the standard says that a function name in this context is converted to the address of the function.

This:

```
(*function)();
```

is the way to use the function (since it's a function pointer).

However, notice that:

```
function()
```

is also accepted, as you can see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1952175/how-to-call-the-function-using-function-pointer).

There is no black magic behind this, C is constructed like this, and function pointers are meant to be used like this, that's the syntax.