# "void value not ignored as it ought to be" but I'm lost where exactly I assign void to anything?

Tags: c, pointers, ode

I am writing a code to integrate some ODEs using a leapfrog method, I have to supply a function including the derivatives to my integration method, however I'm getting a "void value not ignored as it ought to be error". I've gotten this in the past when I've mistaken types with function pointers but as far as I can see the function doesn't assign anything anywhere, it should just execute?

So my source file is here

```
#include "nrutil.h"
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>
void leapvel(int n, double x[], double v[], double dt2, void (*derivs)(double, double [], double []))

{
        double dvdt[n];
        int i;

        (*derivs)(n, x, dvdt);

        for(i = 0; i < n; i++)
                 v[i] += dt2*dvdt[i];

}

void output(int n, double x[], double v[], double t, double dt, void (*derivs)(double, double [], double []))
{
        int i;
        double vv[n], dvdt[n];

        printf("%f", t);
        for(i = 0; i < n; i++)
                printf(" %f", x[i]);

        /*sync velocity*/

        for (i = 0; i < n; i ++)
                vv[i] = v[i];
        if (t > 0)
        {
                (*derivs)(n,x,dvdt);
                for (i = 0; i < n; i ++)
                        vv[i] -= 0.5*dt*dvdt[i];
        }

        printf("\n");
}

void leap(int n, double x[], double v[], double* t, double dt, void (*derivs)(double, double [], double []))
{
        double dvdt[n];
        int i;

        for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
                x[i] += dt*v[i];

        (*derivs)(n, x, dvdt);

        for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
                v[i] += dt*dvdt[i];

        *t += dt;
}

void leapfrog(int n, double x[], double v[], double t, double dt, double t_max, void (*derivs)(double, double [], double []))
{
/* integration time! */

/* parameters, the user has to set these, and to be honest it's going to be cumbersome either way in command line or just editing the code */
/* but since we have to run this twice! */

/* double t = 0, x[n] = {0}, v[n] = {1};
double t_max = 15, dt = 1;*/

/*this is the number of equations in derivs*/
/*int n = 1*/

int i;


output(n, x, v, t, dt, *derivs);
leapvel(n, x, v, 0.5*dt, *derivs);

while (t < t_max)
{
        leap(n, x, v, &t, dt, *derivs);
        output(n, x, v, t, dt, *derivs);
}

}
```

**This is referenced in a short file** I do intend to make a header once I figure this out as it's better practice than simply just including the source file however, for now this is what I have

```
#include <math.h>


void leapfrog(int n, double x[], double v[], double t, double dt, double t_max, void (*derivs)(double, double [], double []));

void derivs(int n, double x[], double dvdt[])
{
        int i;
        double accel = 0.0;

        for(i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
                accel = -x[i];
                dvdt[i] = accel;
        }


}

int main()
{

/*frog goes {number of equations], {x initial conditions}, {v initial}, [t bottom], [t step], [t max], derivs(n,
 * x[], dvdt[]) */
int n = 1;
double x[n];
double v[n];
x[0] = 0;
v[0] = 1;

double t = 0;
double dt = 1;
double t_max = 15;
double dvdt[n];


leapfrog(n, x, v, t, dt, t_max, *derivs(n, x, dvdt)); /*I get the error on this line*/

return 0;

}
```

I'm probably missing something obvious here but I'm not sure.

I've tried to make the function a void pointer type function but that obviously is dangerous, and has undefined behavior, so I have a pointer to a void function now, but that gives this error. If I remove the arguments it has other weird behavior. I'm not sure how to make this work. Removing the arguments gives too few arguments obviously as it's declare above, but when I give it what it wants it gives the error.

This means the error is probably in the source file shown off first, but I can't seem to find it in there, as far as I can see I don't directly assign it to anything so all should be fine.

Comment: For which line do you get that error? Please identify it with a comment.

Comment: @SupportUkraine Please do not ask for a line number. They might answer with a number.

Comment: What happens when you pass `derivs` to `leapfrog` instead? Note that the first argument of `derivs` is  `int` not a `double`.

Comment: I have added a comment but I get it on this line "leapfrog(n, x, v, t, dt, t_max, *derivs(n, x, dvdt));" Line 44 in the code block.

If I pass derivs without the * I get "invalid use of void expression" on the same line

Comment: You don't pass a function pointer like that. Further the types doesn't match

Comment: To bob, I did correct the int/double mismatch between the functions now however that still gives me "void value not ignored as it ought to be" on line 44, the commented line

Comment: `leapfrog(n, x, v, t, dt, t_max, *derivs(n, x, dvdt));` --> `leapfrog(n, x, v, t, dt, t_max, derivs);`

Comment: and read: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1952175/how-can-i-call-a-function-using-a-function-pointer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to pass the function `derivs` as an argument to a function, you just write `derivs`. Just like the way you pass any other variable. You don't write `sin(double x)`; it's just `sin(x)`. Same with functions.

Here, you are *calling* `derivs` and then attempting to dereference its non-existent return value:

```c
leapfrog(n, x, v, t, dt, t_max, *derivs(n, x, dvdt))
```

The compiler objects, because there is obviously no return value to dereference. But the real error was writing a function call rather than just providing the function. You should write:

```c
leapfrog(n, x, v, t, dt, t_max, derivs)
```

For obscure reasons, the compiler might not complain about this incorrect function call:

```c
output(n, x, v, t, dt, *derivs);
```

where you are attempting to pass the function itself rather than a pointer to a function. If you look at the prototype for `output`, you'll see that the last parameter is a pointer to a function, so that's what you should pass it. Anyway, there is no other option, because in C functions are not usable as objects; you can only use pointers to functions. So that call (and the other similar ones) should be written as `output(n, x, v, t, dt, derivs)`. Unsurprisingly, that's pretty similar to the way `leapfrog` should be called.

Comment: Thank you so much, this was precisely it. I'm new to C and this actually explains a lot. This is a great response. If I had 15 feedback I'd give you an upvote